# Linux Terminal: how to capture or watch other terminal session

Tags: linux, terminal

Let say, I access to a server using ssh. In the same time, there is another person accessing that server.

Is it possible to watch what is going on in that person's terminal. Meaning, Can I just watch what he is typing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If the other person is using the Linux console, you can use [conspy](http://linux.die.net/man/1/conspy).

Answer (score 14):

If you mean that the other person *wants* you to see his console, you two can use screen to share a terminal. See http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Multiuser-Session.html for a full description of how to do it.

Comment: Is it possible for a root user to see others' consoles which is not expected to be watched?

Comment: My answer is about sharing a terminal, not snooping on someone else's. I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 7):

I also use an approach similar to what Maze said. This is a unidirectional sharing with read-only for the guest. This is how it works:

1) The host starts the `script` command writing somewhere where the guest has read access and set the permits as required, for example:

```
$ script -f /tmp/shared_screen
Script was started....
$ chmod 640 /tmp/shared_screen
$ chgrp shared_group /tmp/shared_screen
```

The `-f` flushes the contents permanently so you'll have a very low delay

2) The guest starts dumping the content of the file:

```
$ tail -f /tmp/shared_screen
```

In this case `-f` causes tail to wait on more output from the file. Use `ctrl-C` to stop displaying the file contents.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the small tool [script](https://ayaz.wordpress.com/2006/11/19/script1-logging-terminal-sessions-to-files/) for logging the terminal into a file. The observing party can simply [tail -f](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_tail.htm) that file to follow.

This is a much simpler approach, but it works very nicely for most cases

Answer (score 2):

To **capture** what Alice types in a terminal,
and then the next day let Bob see what was typed --
without any risk of Bob accidentally typing anything into that terminal --
Alice can type "showterm" ( http://showterm.io ) in her terminal window to start the recording.

To **share** a terminal so Alice and Bob both see "the same" terminal window and can both type commands into that window,
there seems to be three popular methods:
[Byobu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byobu_(software)), [tmux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/tmux), or [screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen).

([tmate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TMate) is a fork of tmux that works just as well, perhaps better).

- ["How to Share a Terminal Session with Friends" (with Byobu)](https://www.maketecheasier.com/share-terminal-session-with-friends/)
- ["Sharing Terminal Sessions With Tmux And Screen"](https://www.howtoforge.com/sharing-terminal-sessions-with-tmux-and-screen)
- ["ask Ubuntu: Share SSH Session at login"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367438/share-ssh-session-at-login)
- ["Remotely Working Together on a Terminal Session in Linux" (with screen)](http://technonstop.com/screen-commands-for-terminal-sharing)
- [Ubuntu: "HOWTO: Connect to another user's console terminal using 'screen'"](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=299286)
- ["HowTo Share A Terminal Session Using Screen"](http://wiki.networksecuritytoolkit.org/nstwiki/index.php/HowTo_Share_A_Terminal_Session_Using_Screen)

Answer (score 2):

Something nice and easy:

```
watch -n 1 cat /dev/vcsa1
```

`watch -n 1` refers for the time to refresh.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try `"cat /dev/vcsa1"`

Answer (score 1):

Well depending on whether its for 'live' or 'ondemand' purposes, you could replay it online with a service like [www.playterm.org](http://www.playterm.org).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to share a session on a machine behind a firewall or NAT, you can use the open-source terminal sharing program [Termbeamer](http://termbeamer.com).

Answer (score 0):

In CoCalc the Linux terminal are all collaborative. You can watch the other person type, you can also type, and there is a chat on the side for discussions.   See https://cocalc.com/features/terminal  and also you can install https://github.com/sagemathinc/cocalc-docker on your own server (so you don't need to use cocalc.com).

Disclaimer: I mostly wrote these terminals, since I wanted to be able to collaboratively use command line math software.