# Log output from two terminals side by side in a single file

Tags: bash, shell, logging, io-redirection, iterm

I am running two scripts on two terminals in iTerm on Mac. On one terminal a series of tests are being run and the second terminal continuously prints the temperature at repeated intervals. There is no synchronization between the two scripts.

```
  Terminal1     Terminal2
    Test1         50C
                  51C
                  52C
    Test2         49C
                  53C
```

What I want to do is to capture these two outputs side by side and save it to a file.

The output can look like this:

```
    Test1         50C
    Test1         51C
    Test1         52C
    Test2         49C
    Test2         53C
```

It need not be the exact same format as above but at least it should be clear that when a Test was running, what the temperature samples were at that time. The output need not be a live output. It's okay if it is collated later.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353253/linux-terminal-how-to-capture-or-watch-other-terminal-session

Comment: Do you need this output live or are you looking to collate this from log files after the fact?

Comment: I don't need it live. Its okay if I have it later.

Comment: What if you just >> both outputs to the same file?

Comment: I can't do that because in the terminal where tests are running there might be a steady flow of output which will mess up temperature and tests in a haphazard way.

Comment: I've posted a solution, did it help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

first=$1
second=$2

actual=""
while IFS= read -r lineA && IFS= read -r lineB <&3; do
    if [[ -z "${lineA// }" ]]; then
        echo "$actual   $lineB"
    else
        echo "$lineA    $lineB"
        actual=$lineA
    fi
done <$first 3<$second
```

Where $1 and $2 are the two files passed by arguments.

Usage:

```
./join.sh first.txt second.txt
```

Regards.